# Maximo Anywhere After clonning application Barcode scanning not working

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, maximo-anywhere

After I clonned application Barcode scanning notworking its throwing "Class not found" error 
this is the only messgae that i found it , i tried this on diffrent versions starting from 7.6.1 till 7.6.2.1 i opened a ticket with IBM and they taking to much time .
i did all of the steps specially barcode stuff and i noticed that after cloning native folder size is the half i most of the lib folder is not clonned and prefrence.xml file is missing and the configuration.xml file has missing lines

Any one has any idea how to fix it

=== handled: false Logger.js:295
[TRACE] Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds Logger.js:318
Class not found 
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/js/platform/codeScanner/nativeBridge/CodeScannerPlugin.js:79:151
    at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/worklight/cordova.js:292:52)
    at processMessage (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/worklight/cordova.js:1083:17)
    at processMessages (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/worklight/cordova.js:1106:9)
    ----------------------------------------
Error
    at Promise.then._7d5.then (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:280450)
    at declare.findByScan (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/js/platform/handlers/CodeScannerHandler.js:51:19)
    at null. (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:1108:47)
    at HTMLSpanElement. (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:290422)
    at Function.on.emit (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:567559)
    at _1187.fire (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:649620)
    at _129f.release (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:699759)
    at _1187._process (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:649405)
    at HTMLSpanElement. (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:290005)
    at HTMLSpanElement. (file:///data/data/com.WorkExecutionTransco/files/www/default/dojo/dojo.js:2:182065) dojo.js:2

Comment: Have you ensured that the Cordova plugin - JS and native code - is present in the right place?

Comment: the first stage it wasn't there when I moved it.
the idea is in Maximo Anywhere we have the original application is working fine IBM provide steps in order to clone it I found a lot of missing things.

the cloned application not working probably

Comment: Can you explain what this "cloning" is? What exactly is cloned?

Comment: in Maximo Anywhere Product we have a script in order to copy the application with a different name

Comment: From the error stack , it gives the impression of missing pieces in the Cordova plugin. Can you verify manually, between the source application folder and clone , if all the files made it - specifically around the native and the JS files - also the mapping in the config.xml , plugins.js etc is intact.